# what's the best way to use application constants in spring xml configuration?

Tags: java, spring, constants, spring-el

I want to use my application constants within spring xml configuration.

I know to do that with spring SpEl with something like this:

```
<bean class="example.SomeBean">
    <property name="anyProperty" value="#{ T(example.AppConfiguration).EXAMPLE_CONSTANT}" />
    <!-- Other config -->
</bean>
```

So, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but why to have constant in class and not in property file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use `<util:constant>` (See [C.2.2 The util schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util)):

```
<bean class="example.SomeBean">
    <property name="anyProperty">
       <util:constant static-field="example.AppConfiguration.EXAMPLE_CONSTANT" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

It's debatable as to whether that's any better, though. Your SpEL version is more succinct.

Another option is to use the Java configuration style, which is more natural (see [4.12 Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)):

```
@Bean
public SomeBean myBean() {
    SomeBean bean = new SomeBean();
    bean.setProperty(EXAMPLE_CONSTANT);  // using a static import
    return bean;
}
```